# Flutter. When copy List to List got error

Tags: json, dart

I want copy List data with hostId values form Json to empty list pcBusy. I wrote code, but I get the error **"_TypeError (type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'List')"**.

Thanks for help!)

```
List pcBusy = [];

void fetchDataStandart() async {
  final urlAuth =
      Uri.parse('http://185.XX.XXX.XXX/api/usersessions/activeinfo');
  final response = await http
      .get(urlAuth, headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List listPc = List.from(json.decode(response.body)['result']);

    for (int i = 0; i < listPc.length; i++) {
      pcBusy = listPc[i]['hostId'];
    }
    print(pcBusy);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Ошибка получения данных');
  }
}
```

Comment: your return value is int, so it can not be assigned to a list, try to print List.from(json.decode(response.body)['result']) or json.decode(response.body)['result'] to see what it prints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the `.add()` method to add elements to a `List` (what you are doing is using `=` to assign the `int` to your `pcBusy` variable which gives an error since `int` is not `List` and you cannot in Dart change the type of a variable on runtime):

```
List<int> pcBusy = [];

void fetchDataStandart() async {
  final urlAuth =
      Uri.parse('http://185.XX.XXX.XXX/api/usersessions/activeinfo');
  final response = await http
      .get(urlAuth, headers: <String, String>{'authorization': basicAuth});

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    List listPc = List.from(json.decode(response.body)['result']);

    for (int i = 0; i < listPc.length; i++) {
      pcBusy.add(listPc[i]['hostId'] as int);
    }
    print(pcBusy);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Ошибка получения данных');
  }
}
```

I have also tried to add some minimal typing. In general, don't use `List` unless you really want `List<dynamic>`.

Comment: Hi! How update the code to refresh the pcBusy List by adding new values, not only add values. This is print "I/flutter (17340): [S14, S18, S19, S12, S14, S18, S19, S12]" when I click two times.

Comment: Instead of `List<int>` you can try use `Set<int>`. A `Set` cannot contain duplicated values.